# What programs and packages are updated by the update manager?

Tags: update-manager, deb

The update manager periodically checks for available updates for packages installed through the Ubuntu Software Center. Does the manager also check for available updates for the programs installed via deb file (for example: skype, opera, virtualbox, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is registered in your `/etc/sources.list` will get updated.

**Skype**

- See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

The source code is proprietary and not available for modification so Ubuntu will *never* update it. The version in the repositories is as is and will only get updated when a new Ubuntu is released. Updating has to be done by Microsoft.

**VirtualBox**

Installing this: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads will not get updates from Ubuntu.
VBox is in the repositories so use that one.

**Opera**

- See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser

> Install opera for the shared version or opera-static for static version. The reason it's recommended is that when you update the rest of your packages (e.g. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade), Opera will be updated too without having to tend to Opera specifically.
>
> There is a generic Opera repository available at http://deb.opera.com (with full description of how to add it).

The recommended way for installing Opera also means it will get updated. Otherwise you need to take care of it.

Ubuntu is not about having the newest software as soon as possible so if you want bleeding edge you need to take care of your system yourself (or switch to another operating system).

Answer (score 1):

No any manually installed packages (from a .deb file) are not updated, since the Ubuntu Software Center (or apt-get) will not know where to get the updated version and if there is a newer version in the repository it will hold the package unless you mark it for update.

However most programs such as Skype and Virtualbox are available from the Software Center and should not be manually installed if you want automatic updates.